# How to change OPTION method to POST?

Tags: http, post, plupload

I use the [next link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2585-chunking-file-uploads-with-plupload-and-coldfusion.htm) in order to send chunking files with plupload.

I change the url parameter in order to send the request to my localhost:

`url: "./upload.cfm"`, was changes to  `url: "localhost/upload"`

As I see, the request is sent, but with request methods: `OPTIONS`.

Why it happens and how I can change it to `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are now making a cross-origin HTTP request, you are triggering a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) in which the browser asks the destination server if your website is allowed to ask browsers to make POST requests to the destination server.

Either configure the destination server to respond to the OPTIONS request with a response granting permissions (after getting that response the browser will make the POST request), or continue to make requests with XHR only to the same origin.

Comment: and I can change the code of the client to make requests with XHR only to the same origin?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. My server is running on localhost:5000, and If I go in the browser of this site, just POST request are sent. The URL in the code above is `url: localhost/upload`. How I pointing to different origin?

Comment: `url: localhost/upload` is a syntax error. Do you mean `url: "http://localhost/upload"`? The default port is 80, which is not port 5000, so the origins are different.

Comment: Yes, I mean `url: "http://localhost:80/upload"`. When I change my server to run on port 80, it still send OPTION request.

Comment: So you are not using `:5000` at all now?

Comment: exactly. Use just 80.

Comment: The HTML document is loaded from `:80` and the Ajax request is going to `:80`? And you are using `http://` for both? And `localhost` for both? (**Exactly** `localhost` not `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, not `http://localhost` and `file://something`?). Then the behaviour you describe should not occur.

Comment: Here the request: `Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://localhost/upload`
the server is listening on port 80.

Comment: And what about the HTML document in which the JS is running?

Comment: `index.cfm`? I try there to put url: `"http://172.0.0.1/upload"` and `url: "http://localhost/upload"`, and it sends the OPTION method.

Comment: What is the complete URL to `index.cfm`?

Comment: `C:\plupload-2.1.2\js\Plupload-Chunking-Demo-master\demo`. is this the problem? Where I should put it?

Comment: `C:\plupload-2.1.2\etc` is a (mangled by Windows) `file://` URI. You are making a request to `http://`. `file://` is not `http://`. Therefore you are making a cross origin request. You need to load the HTML document through HTTP.